# How to use Github Actions to generate a checksum and set env variable?

Tags: shell, github-actions

Would like to generate a checksum via Github Actions and set to env variable CHECKSUM like so:

```
     - name: Create checksum
       run: echo CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 1 foo.zip | awk '{ print $1 }') >> $CHECKSUM
```

but it returns an error:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/b6f2fd2a-359b-4052-a439-4f5b0a629a85.sh: line 1: $CHECKSUM: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setting environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) works differently: you append to a file whose name is stored in the `$GITHUB_ENV` variable, i.e., something like

```yaml
run: |
  echo CHECKSUM="$(shasum foo.zip | awk '{ print $1 }')" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```